# Get the element of an array that has an index given by a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var items = [item1, item2, item3];

var index = Math.random() * items.length;
```

I expect the statement

```
items[index]
```

to return a random item from my array, however it always returns `undefined`. How do I get the item indexed by the `index` variable?

Comment: The `Math.random()` function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `floor` the number befaore using it as subscript:

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
```

That way you'll get integer values for `index` and not floating ones.

Comment: I forgot to get an integer, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need an integer value index, because an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) is organized by positive integer values.

If you use a not integer value, the value is converted to a string (this applies to the integer value, too) and used as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). An in this case, for example `1.22`, the value does not exist in the array and you get `undefined`.

BTW, arrays are objects in Javascript, so all values could be used as key for the array.

```js
var items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);

console.log(items[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.round() to round up the index

```
var index = Math.round(Math.random() * (items.length - 1));
```

Otherwise it could point to something like 2.3 which isn't incöuded in the array